# What sefer has rashei teivot הל''פ?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, jewish-books, acronyms

The Kaf Hahayyim in Yoreh Deah often cites a sefer whose name he abbreviates with the rashei teivot הל''פ. I can't find this acronym in his luach rashei teivot at the beginning of Yoreh Deah volume 1, nor at the beginning of Orach Chayim volume 1.

What halacha sefer is he referring to? What seforim could be identified by the rashei teivot הל''פ?

(Note: the Kaf HaHayyim in Yoreh Deah often cites the Lechem HaPanim, using the rashei teivot לה''פ, and he will often cite הל''פ right after citing the Lechem HaPanim, so הל''פ can't be the Lechem HaPanim)

Comment: @GershonGold: I've edited to clarify my question. I don't think a sentence will help.

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_10169_58.pdf see 22 for example

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a Sefer Halacha Pesuka ([Volume 1](http://hebrewbooks.org/8111) & [Volume 2](http://hebrewbooks.org/8112)) on Yoreh Deah. If you compare the references in the [Kaf Hachayim YD 75](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_10169_58.pdf) to the [Halacha Pesuka 2:75](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8112&st=&pgnum=22) you will see that the references matches.

Comment: Thank you for such a helpful answer. I wasn't expecting to see this much effort go into verifying that the references match.